# Different results when elisp function is run different ways; why?

Tags: emacs, elisp

EDIT: Perhaps (in original post) I used the term "transient" incorrectly (I'm not familiar enough with the jargon yet). What I really mean is that the highlighted region will **disappear** immediately when the user presses a **navigation keys** eg. arrow-keys... (2nd EDIT: I've removed the word "transient")

---

The particular issue of *selecting* a region so the user gets **"cursor-key movement will make highlighting disappear"** has been the bane of my existance recently. I get differnt results depending on how I run the following script.

Why does it give different results, and more specifically, is there a way to make it produce **"cursor-keys make highlighting disappear"** regardless of which mode is running, or whether it is being evaluated while testing? .. CUA mode has this behaviour, but I really need that non CUA mode does it too (and eval, if possible)...

Here are the results, followed by the code. (GNU Emacs 23.1.1)

- CUA mode enabled

  1. Evaluate via `C-x C-e` — both `(call-trans-hi)` and `(trans-hi)`
     *NO-GO*: Both set mark and move point to EOL, but *nothing* is highlighted.
  2. Execute `M-x call-trans-hi`
     ok: Works fine; the region is highlighted and then *disappears* the first time a key is pressed.
  3. Via key binding `C-f1`
     ok: Works fine; the region is highlighted and then *disappears* the first time a key is pressed.
- no CUA mode (pretty much std emacs)

  1. Evaluate via `C-x C-e`
     *NO-GO*: Same as 1. when CUA is enabled.
  2. Execute `M-x call-trans-hi`
     *NO-GO*: The line is highlighted, *but it is sticky!* and requires `C-g` (keyboard-quit) to clear it.
  3. Via key binding `C-f1`
     *NO-GO*: The line is highlighted, *but it is sticky!* and requires `C-g` (keyboard-quit) to clear it.

---

```
 ;test (trans-hi) EOL
 (defun trans-hi ()
   "transient highlight"
     (beginning-of-line)
     (push-mark (point))
     (end-of-line)
     (activate-mark))

 ;test (call-trans-hi) EOL
 (defun call-trans-hi ()
   "call transient highlight"
     (interactive)
     (trans-hi))
 (global-set-key [C-f1] 'call-trans-hi)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the source of `activate-mark`, you can see that it's just setting some variables. I suppose that's why you don't see the mark in both **1.**, because the actual highlighting happens in some stuff that's done when executing functions interactively instead of just calling them.

In the other cases of no CUA-mode, that just how transient highlighting works outside of CUA-mode. If you want the CUA-mode behaviour, use CUA-mode resp. that part of it.

EDIT:

Does this change (the addition of the `setq` line) to `trans-hi` make the highlighting work the way you want?

```
(defun trans-hi ()
  "transient highlight"
  (beginning-of-line)
  (push-mark (point))
  (end-of-line)
  (setq transient-mark-mode (cons 'only transient-mark-mode))
  (activate-mark))
```

Comment: Am I misusing the term transient? I've been reading more and perhaps "transient" is wrong.. So, lets partially ignore that word for a moment. I want the selection to be **visible (ie. highlighted)** after the script finishes.  I've just now been readig one of *Xah Lee's* great tutorials, and I now think that what I just described is called *transient* ..(not quite sure, though), but what I really need is that the *highlighted region* will **disappear** when the user presses a key... (this is what I meant by transient)...  CUA can do it, so it is do-able. I'm after: How do I do *that*?

Comment: PS. I basically don't want CUA mode unless it happens to be currently enabled.. I've mainly included it here becaue I noticed that it does work as I want.. I do however need to cater for both scenarios..  and from that perhaps the evaluate method may be made to work, too...

Comment: I think I may have understood now what you want. Does the code I've added to my answer help?

Comment: *@Rörd:*   Wow!!! I almost can't believe it. I've been grappling with this for so long.. What a relief!  It works! ... You deserve the *Hero of the week* award! Thanks so much...

Comment: — I found a link to the explanation of the command used: [(only . oldval)](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html#index-transient_002dmark_002dmode-2505) .. quoting: *"If the value is (only . oldval), then transient-mark-mode is set to the value oldval after any subsequent command that moves point and is not shift-translated (see shift-translation), or after any other action that would normally deactivate the mark. "* ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the region highlighted when you mark it, you need
to activate the minor mode `transient-mark-mode`.

When a region is highlighted and a character insterted the default is
to disable the highlighting and insert the character at the cursor.

If you wish you can delete the selected region by activating the minor
mode `delete-selection-mode`.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly how `transient-mark-mode` effects this, because I already had `transient-mark-mode` set to `t`...

Comment: Ok my bad, I haven't understood your request.

So I've digged a bit into the `cua-mode` source and it adds a hook on
`post-command-hook` which disables `transient-mark-mode` if an arrow
key is pressed. This is not the standard behavior of
`transient-mark-mode` if you want it you can either enable `cua-mode`
or make your own hook.

Comment: Thanks... :) Me! make a hook! If only I could! I'm too much of an elisp novice ... but I appreciate your help... and my apologies for having changed the angle of my question... (I'm not over the initial hump in the learning curve yet, but I'm getting there...